# How do you make use of a proof of absurdity in Agda for an absurd pattern?

Tags: agda

I'm trying to write my own version of `foldr1`, which takes a non-empty `Vec A n` (with proof `n ≡ zero → ⊥`), and a binary operation `A → A → A` and returns a value of type A. That is:

```
foldr1 : {A : Set} {n : ℕ} (n ≡ zero → ⊥) → (A → A → A) → Vec A n → A
```

The issue is, trying to apply the absurd pattern to the case `foldr1 p binop [] ()` the complier says:

> Cannot eliminate type A with pattern () (did you supply too many
>   arguments?)

Since the compiler can't deduce absurdity on it's own, I'd like to be able to provide the proof manually, doing something like: `foldr1 p binop [] (p refl)` where `refl : n \equiv zero`, but the compiler does not like that syntax.

Is there a way to provide the proof of absurdity manually in Agda to construct absurd patterns? If not, how can I get the compiler to deduce that what I have written is indeed an absurd pattern? My code is something like:

```
open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality 

data ⊥ : Set where

binfold₁ : {n : ℕ} → {A : Set} → (n ≡ zero → ⊥) → Vec A n → (A → A → A) → A 
binfold₁ p [] _⊗_ ()
binfold₁ p (x ∷ v) _⊗_ = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either define `⊥-elim : {A : Set}  → ⊥ → A` or use the empty type defined in `Data.Empty` that already defines it:

```
open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Empty
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality 

binfold₁ : {n : ℕ} → {A : Set} → (n ≡ zero → ⊥) → Vec A n → (A → A → A) → A 
binfold₁ p []      _⊗_ = ⊥-elim (p refl)
binfold₁ p (x ∷ v) _⊗_ = {!!}
```

But you can also pick another type where, instead of asking for a proof `n ≡ zero → ⊥`, you ask for a vector of type `Vec A (suc n)`:

```
binfold₁' : {n : ℕ} → {A : Set} → Vec A (suc n) → (A → A → A) → A 
binfold₁' (x ∷ v) _⊗_ = {!!}
```